# How to use rpython translator to convert my python script into pypy?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, pypy, rpython

I am using python 3.7 in windows 10 64-bit platform.

My python script contains mainly pyopengl graphics. My application works okay with python but I want to speed it up so I am trying to use pypy3 interpreter but while running it shows below error:

```
"C:\Users\RND2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.wrapperFunction( self.baseFunction, *args, **named )
  File "C:\Users\RND2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\VERSION\GL_1_5.py", line 89, in glBufferData
    return baseOperation( target, size, data, usage )
  File "C:\Users\RND2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 43, in __call__
    return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
  File "C:\Users\RND2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\OpenGL\wrapper.py", line 693, in wrapperCall
    result = wrappedOperation( *cArguments )
  File "C:\Users\RND2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\pypy3.6-v7.3.1-win32\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 425, in __call__
    self.__name__, self.__name__,
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glBufferData, check for bool(glBufferData) before calling
```

I have downloaded pypy3.6 from https://www.pypy.org/download.html
for above case I am using pypy3 only without including Rpython.

But now I want to implement it through Rpython but don't know the exact sequence. I am a beginner.

Please help me to solve my problem. I will appreciate your effort or help.

Comment: Your program shows a Python crash, which you should debug in the usual way for Python.  Maybe it comes from some detail like you have installed a different version of pyopengl or some other library, or during installation of that library it found different DLLs (e.g. maybe you are comparing the 64-bit CPython with the 32-bit PyPy, on Windows).  Well I can't really help you on your specific problem, but I just wanted to say that asking about RPython is irrelevant.  RPython is just the internal language in which PyPy is made.

Comment: okay .than you for your response@Armin Rigo .here i have one question which is , is python version means 32-bit or 64-bit affects on pypy? yes as you have noticed , i am using pypy of 32-bit but as per my understanding python and pypy are different interpreter. i want to use pypy instead of python actually. and i have doubt about pyopengl version but how can i find out that which version is appropriate for my application?